# Commit file in SVN without working copy using SVN uri path

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0, sharpsvn

I'm new to SharpSVN, i have a aspx page in which i need to display a file content from SVN, change the content and commit the file in SVN from memorystream without working copy. I am able to get the file content using memorystream and display in web page, but is there any way to commit content from web page using SVN uri path?

thanks in advance..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't commit files without a working copy.

Comment: This is incorrect. See other answers for how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, you can using the svnmucc command line tool

```
svnmucc put path-to-source path-to-remote
```

This won't let you use streams, but you could look at the source of the tool to write something that worked off streams.

Answer (score 0):

You can commit using Subversion remote API. Here's the [example](http://vcs.atspace.co.uk/2012/07/20/subversion-remote-api-committing-without-working-copy/) for Java language, but the same API is used in other languages (C, Perl, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Streams allowed with `svnmucc -- put - path-to-remote`.